# Mockito.verify didn't see method exectution, even if it was

Tags: android, mockito, rx-java2, powermock

The error I have:
[image: Error I have]
The code with the error:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(PotatoProvider::class, PotatoConsumer::class)
class WantedButNotInvoked {
    @Mock
    lateinit var potatoConsumer: PotatoConsumer

    @Test
    fun potato() {
        Observable.just(Potato()).subscribe(potatoConsumer)        
        verify(potatoConsumer).accept(Potato())
        //verify(potatoConsumer).accept(any()) //-> This fails too with the same reason
    }
}

data class Potato(val value: Int = 1)

class PotatoConsumer : Consumer<Potato> {
    override fun accept(t: Potato?) {
        println(t)
    }
}
```

So I making subscribe with this mock(potatoConsumer), and the rxJava have called 'accept', and mockito mark it as interaction, but mockito thinks this interaction is not what I'm expecting, why?

Versions of libraries used her:

```
mockitoVersion = '2.8.9'
mockitoAndroidVersion = '2.7.22'
powerMockVersion="2.0.2"
kotlinMockito="2.1.0"
rxKotlin = "2.3.0"
rxJavaVersion = "2.2.10"
```

#### Kinda workaround

1. Some fields mocked by powermock, fails on 'verify', but fields mocked with mockito is not;
2. Mockito can't mock not opened fields, without `mock-maker-inline`, but mockito conflicts with Powermock mock-maker-inline;
3. Powermock can delegate calls of mock-maker-inline to other mock-maker-inline(https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMock-Configuration)
4. Use Mockito.mock on the failed fields instead of @Mock/Powermock mock injection

Example of the "green" potato test method using PowerMockRunner

```java
    @Test
    fun potato() {
        potatoConsumer = mock() // <-
        Observable.just(Potato()).subscribe(potatoConsumer)
        verify(potatoConsumer).accept(potato)
    }
```

Comment: What version of `rx-java2`, `mockito` and `powermock` are you using? Also - in case you haven't noticed - you could remove the whole `fakePotatoProvider` from the example and just go with `Observable.just(Potato()).subscribe(potatoConsumer)` instead (but that won't solve your issue).

Comment: Thx for your answer, you are right, I simplified the code by your example and provide lib versions

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `PowerMock` but I tried this test and it passes:

```
    @Test
    fun potato() {

        fakePotatoProvider = Mockito.mock(PotatoProvider::class.java)
        potatoConsumer = Mockito.mock(PotatoConsumer::class.java)

        `when`(fakePotatoProvider.getObservable()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Potato()))
        fakePotatoProvider.getObservable().subscribe(potatoConsumer)
        verify(potatoConsumer).accept(Potato())
    }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, If I make classes and methods open, and remove all Powermockito stuff - the test is green. And I have no idea, WTF is going on. I have added Powermock tag to the question, I hope someone will see it and will help to solve. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you aren't passing the same instance of `Potato()`. Try to refactor your code to this

```
@Test
fun potato() {
  val testPotato = Potato()  
  `when`(fakePotatoProvider.getObservable()).thenReturn(Observable.just(testPotato))

  fakePotatoProvider.getObservable().subscribe(potatoConsumer)

  verify(potatoConsumer).accept(testPotato)    
}
```

As I mentioned above, the reason why *it might* be failing is the constant creation of new instances when passing your `Potato` object, hance that comparison fails.

Comment: Tried, same result.
And it does not explain why `any() ` show same error